# How to determine which exception is which?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I made an login system but i want to notify people on invalid login.
I want to determine which exception has been catched so i can notify the user what is wrong.

```
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuthException: 'Exception occured while authenticating.
Url: https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key={0}
Request Data: {"email":"","password":"","returnSecureToken":true}
Response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_EMAIL",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_EMAIL",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Reason: InvalidEmailAddress'
```

```
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuthException: 'Exception occured while authenticating.
Url: https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key={0}
Request Data: {"email":"admin@something.com","password":"admni","returnSecureToken":true}
Response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_PASSWORD",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_PASSWORD",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Reason: WrongPassword'
```

Comment: catch the exception and check for its `message` or the `reason`.. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You shouldn't. Specifying which of user or pass was invalid just makes it easier for attackers.

Comment: those are the catched messages, i want to notify people on ui. is password wrong or is email invalid. but i dont know how to determine which is which.

Comment: the most naive implementation is this: `if(exception.message.Contains("INVALID_PASSWORD") ...`. Did you try that? Of course it´s not nice, but it gets its job done.

Comment: no, that makes sense. thanks.